# java singleton with double check

Tags: java, singleton

As we know, simple double check has problem because of the command resorting by the JVM.

```
class MyClass {

    private String Name;

    private static Object o = new Object();
    private static MyClass Instance=null;

    private MyClass(){
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        Name="test case";
    }
    public static MyClass GetInstance(){
        if(Instance==null){
            synchronized(o){
                if(Instance==null){
                    Instance = new MyClass();
                    //MyClass obj = new MyClass();
                    //Instance = obj;
                }
            }
        }
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

If I replace the `Instance = new MyClass();` to the commented lines. Does this work?

Comment: No. Just make it [`volatile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java).

Comment: MyClass obj = new MyClass();  will return a new instance and then Instance is assigned with the object .Why this not work ?I really don't know why.

Comment: There's almost no point to double-checked locking, even with a correct implementation using `volatile`. Lazy-instantiated singletons should use the [initialization on demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).

Answer (score 1):

No this doesn't work. Consider thread A and B; thread A sees that `Instance` is `null` and enters the synchronized block to make an instance of `MyClass` and assign it to the field `Instance`.

Due to the rules of the Java Memory Model, re-ordering may occur and a partially initialized or even uninitialized object of `MyClass` can be assigned to `Instance`. Now thread B goes into the same `GetInstance` method and sees that `Instance` is not null, never enters a synchronized block on the same monitor as thread A and then returns an object that is not fully initialized.

Whether or not you split the initialization into two lines of code or leaving it on one line has absolutely no significance for this problem: re-ordering can occur in either case. The Java compiler could legally compile both versions of your code to the same bytecode (although the current compiler won't)

Comment: You mean compiler may optimize the code ,as a result no difference will make. Thanks a lot .